# How to modify this Fail2ban regex to reject GET wp-login.php?

Tags: regex

i have added rule into fail2ban to reject all wp login attemps

```
 failregex = ^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+ <HOST> .*POST.*/wp-login\.php HTTP.*
```

i would like to add the parameter GET to all login attempt (for reject them also )

so far i tried this

```
 failregex = ^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+ <HOST> .*"(GET|POST).*/wp-login\.php HTTP.*
```

or

```
failregex = ^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+ <HOST> .*(GET|POST).*/wp-login\.php HTTP.*
```

but this does not work for GET parameter i still see it in access.log

thx you very much to help me

Comment: Could you post a sample of the access logs?